# Close Ports - Which ones and how?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, security, scanning, ports

I am wanting to close ports, to stop myself from been vulnerable to attacks/exploits

What would be the best way to locate open ports on my computer and closing them to prevent such activities?

Thanks

Comment: in windows powershell, you can view your ports in a LISTENing state with `netstat -abno | findstr LISTENING` or in linux with `netstat -ntlup`.  in short, a port is opened by a program. if you want to change that, then you change it in the program. anyway you look at it, managing the program to control that port is the best approach. it's only when the situation is more complicated that you want to consider firewalling. etc.

Comment: also note that unless you have forwarded ports on your gateway router, none of your ports should be open from the Internet's perspective. scan you site with the GRC port scanning tool, or try something like canyouseeme.org to review ports that are open to the internet (not just your LAN).

Answer (score 0):

> Close Ports - Which ones and how?

Windows Firewall with default settings does this for you. You should not be trying to over-ride Windows Firewall by setting individual ports.

Make sure the Windows Firewall is ON  - that is default.

If you have a router, make sure the Router Firewall is also on and is set to default. Make sure any outside access is turned off.

Do not open Router ports for port forwarding.

Firewall security is easier and stronger than port security.

Here is a screen shot of inbound rules and you can add rules to close off an app you do not want accessing.

[image: Firewall settings]

Comment: Thanks for that John! So my windows firewall security would stop someone from exploiting an open port ? The issue is, I have strong suspicions a house mate off mine had used Nmap or something similar and is doing stuff he shouldn't be. I do well financially in the digital marketing space and believe he is doing this as a way of knowledge finding, rather than anything malicious, so I am trying to find the best ways to defend myself against it and possibly identify who could be doing it. We are on a shared network :(

Comment: Use the Firewall on your own computer to keep unknown traffic out and then your outgoing traffic can be recognized by the firewall inbound. Still much better than individual ports. You can go into firewall settings to close out the NMAP traffic as well.

Comment: I added a screen shot to help you with adding apps you do not want to inbound rules.

Comment: Thank you so much John, you have been extremely helpful and very knowledgeable. Appreciate the time you took to reply and send screenshots